# minifilter driver append to user buffer in post operation

Tags: c, windows, kernel, windows-kernel, minifilter

I'm learning about minifilter drivers. I want to append some text to every opened .txt file in notepad++ but for some reason it doesn't work. What am I missing here?

```
CONST FLT_OPERATION_REGISTRATION Callbacks[] = {

    { IRP_MJ_READ,
      0,
      PreRead,
      PostRead},
    { IRP_MJ_OPERATION_END }
};

FLT_POSTOP_CALLBACK_STATUS
PostRead (
    _Inout_ PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data,
    _In_ PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects,
    _In_opt_ PVOID CompletionContext,
    _In_ FLT_POST_OPERATION_FLAGS Flags
    )
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER( FltObjects );
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER( CompletionContext );
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER( Flags );

    FLT_POSTOP_CALLBACK_STATUS Status = FLT_POSTOP_FINISHED_PROCESSING;

    // Make sure caller is user-mode process and it's IRP operation just to be safe
    if (Data->RequestorMode != UserMode || KeGetCurrentIrql() != PASSIVE_LEVEL || !FLT_IS_IRP_OPERATION(Data))
        return Status;

    // We only care about 1 process
    if (strcmp(PsGetProcessImageFileName(PsGetCurrentProcess()), "notepad++.exe") != 0)
        return Status;

    PVOID* Buffer;
    PULONG Length; // NOTE: this is buffer length, not string length, string "test" has length of 4 but it can be read into buffer with length 1024
    FltDecodeParameters(Data, NULL, &Buffer, &Length, NULL);

    UNICODE_STRING TargetExtension = RTL_CONSTANT_STRING(L"txt");
    UNICODE_STRING FileExtension = { 0 };
    UNICODE_STRING FileName = { 0 };
    FltParseFileName(&Data->Iopb->TargetFileObject->FileName, &FileExtension, NULL, &FileName);
    if (RtlCompareUnicodeString(&FileExtension, &TargetExtension, TRUE) == 0) // check if it's txt extension
    {
       // B[0] = 'b'; // this works
        FltLockUserBuffer(Data);
        strcat((LPSTR)Data->Iopb->Parameters.Read.ReadBuffer, "hello");
        FltSetCallbackDataDirty(Data);
        DbgPrint("Filename: %wZ , Length in bytes to read: %lu buffer: %s \n", FileName, *Length, (LPSTR)Data->Iopb->Parameters.Read.ReadBuffer);
    }

    return Status;
}
```

Data->Iopb->Parameters.Read.MdlAddress is always NULL in this case

Do I need to create a new buffer in this case? Or can I append to the existing one? It seems to have  enough length (131072 bytes)

Note that it works when I replace a single character, but strcat doesn't work. I even tried using `RtlStringCchCatA`

I'm sure I must be missing something but I don't know what.

[image]

Comment: @GabrielBercea I solved it already. Yeah it's missing a couple of things, like lack of __try and __except. "So much" is exaggeration :) it's just a few lines of code.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a code to get buffer to update in post-read operation callback.

```
PostRead()
{
    if (Data->Iopb->Parameters.Read.MdlAddress != NULL)
    {
        pBuf = MmGetSystemAddressForMdlSafe(Data->Iopb->Parameters.Read.MdlAddress, NormalPagePriority);
        if (pBuf == NULL)
        {
            Data->IoStatus.Status       = STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;
            Data->IoStatus.Information  = 0;
        }
    }
    else if (FlagOn(Data->Flags, FLTFL_CALLBACK_DATA_SYSTEM_BUFFER) || FlagOn(Data->Flags, FLTFL_CALLBACK_DATA_FAST_IO_OPERATION))
    {
        pBuf = Data->Iopb->Parameters.Read.ReadBuffer;
    }
    else
    {
        if (!FltDoCompletionProcessingWhenSafe(Data, FltObjects, CompletionContext, Flags, PostReadWhenSafe,    &returnStatus))
        {
            Data->IoStatus.Status       = STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
            Data->IoStatus.Information  = 0;
        }
    }
}

PostReadWhenSafe()
{
    status = FltLockUserBuffer(Data);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        Data->IoStatus.Status       = status;
        Data->IoStatus.Information  = 0;
        return FLT_POSTOP_FINISHED_PROCESSING;
    }
    pBuf = MmGetSystemAddressForMdlSafe(Data->Iopb->Parameters.Read.MdlAddress, NormalPagePriority);
    if (pBuf == NULL)
    {
        Data->IoStatus.Status       = STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;
        Data->IoStatus.Information  = 0;
    }
    return FLT_POSTOP_FINISHED_PROCESSING;
}
```

Add your string to 'pBuf' and increase Data->IoStatus.Information.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to append the length of appended string to `Data->IoStatus.Information` and it worked. Note that `FltSetCallbackDataDirty` is redundant when you do this.

https://community.osr.com/discussion/271422/when-should-call-fltsetcallbackdatadirty

It seems you don't need a call to `FltLockUserBuffer` in this case as well.